# Memory leak in GTK# + Cairo + Pango

Tags: memory-leaks, mono, gtk#, cairo, pango

I'm using Mono + GTK# + Cairo + Pango on Ubuntu 12.04 and I found some memory leaks when using a `Pango.Layout` object.

I'm drawing some animation with a framerate of about 30 fps and my memory only increases. I remove a lot of code and here is what remains:

```
void OnDraw(DrawingArea area)
{
    Cairo.Context context = Gdk.CairoHelper.Create(area.GdkWindow);

    using (var lay = Pango.CairoHelper.CreateLayout(context))
    {
        // Nothing.  
    }

    ((IDisposable) context.Target).Dispose();
    ((IDisposable) context).Dispose();
}
```

Without the `Pango.CairoHelper.CreateLayout` call the memory remains stable, but with it increases for about 10k per second which is clearly unacceptable.

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is Mono + GTK# + Cairo + Pango ready for production?

```
Mono version : 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2
GTK# version : 2.12.10-2ubuntu4
Pango version : 1.30.0-0ubuntu3.1
uname : Linux ######-VirtualBox 3.2.0-29-generic-pae #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 27 17:25:43 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there have been some fixes in Gtk# bindings that have not been released yet.

For example [this memory leak fix](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/commit/d6ad5db84c659d54770874e2f7d7eeca466ddf4b).

So if I were you, I would try first with [the gtk-sharp upstream version of the 2.12 branch](https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/tree/gtk-sharp-2-12-branch). If that doesn't work, maybe you can spot the memory leak yourself and propose a fix? Thanks.

Comment: I found a workaround by calling `Pango.CairoHelper.CreateLayout` only once and then calling `Pango.CairoHelper.UpdateLayout` each time I want to draw my scene.